# Can you say "do an analysis to something or somebody"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions

My teacher left an assignment to "Do SWOT analysis to yourself", shouldn't it be "on yourself"? Or just use the verb "analyze" instead of "analysis" to make that sentence, I guess what I'm going for is what seems naturally a native speaker would say.

Comment: It would be good if you edit your question to tell us what you think is wrong and why. You might want to research phrases using analysis like analysis of and analysis on.

Comment: See [ask].  The more details you give the better the chance of a useful answer.  It looks like a rapidly written assignment, that could be clearer, perhaps "on yourself" but nothing that interferes with general comprehension

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

I'd probably use "on yourself" or "of yourself." While there isn't much difference and either way would work, "to" has a more proactive connotation than the others. Since analyzing something isn't very proactive, I would stick with "on."

It sounds like this analysis is an assignment, so I would also stick with the noun.